# How to make git clean recurse into submodules

Tags: git

Is there a way to make `git clean` clean untracked files in submodules? The answer has to be in the form of `git clean <something>` because I need to use it with Gitlab's `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS`.

I've tried `git clean -ffd` which *sounds* like it should do the job from the man page:

> -d: Normally, when no  is specified, git clean will not recurse into untracked directories to avoid removing too much. Specify -d to have it recurse into such directories as well. If a  is specified, -d is irrelevant; all untracked files matching the specified paths (with exceptions for nested git directories mentioned under --force) will be removed.

> -f, --force: If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f or -i. Git will refuse to modify untracked nested git repositories (directories with a .git subdirectory) unless a second -f is given.

I guess a "nested git directory" is different from a submodule.

It doesn't look like there is a solution; just thought I'd double check here.

To re-iterate **`git submodule foreach` is not what I am looking for; it must be `git clean <something>`.**